Send email using Powershell and OAuth2
My app uses a Powershell script to send email.
Does anybody know if this is compatible with the new specs introduced in Gmail / Hotmail / Outlook (OAuth2 etc) and coming from October?
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Temp\This.ps1

Where "This.ps1" file is:
try
{
$Email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("test <[sender mail goes here]>", "[receiver mail goes here]", "[subject goes here]", "")
$Attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\Temp\Test.PDF")
$Email.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$Email.ReplyToList.Add("[sender mail goes here]")
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("[sender mail goes here]", "[app pass gows here]")
$SMTPClient.Send($Email)
}
catch
{
$Error[0].Exception.Message | Out-File ('C:\Temp\Email.log')
}


Perhaps you can share a link to an announcement or some documentation from either email provider about the supposed changes you're concerned about?

NetworkCredential is windows credentials and not OAUTH2 credentials.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth.  Powershell is written in Net library so any Net feature can be used in PS.

So this my script is not going to work... I need a new script to do the job, so the users will just update the app and not notice any difference... Is there an example?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/14114704?hl=en
